# How to attach user to request object

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm using JWT for authentication in a django rest framework.
It works like this:

1. Creating a JWT token

```py
token = jwt.encode(payload, os.environ.get('SECRET'), algorithm='HS256')
```

2. Sending the JWT token as a cookie with the httponly flag

```py
response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
```

3. To verfiy that user is logged in any view I look for the cookie and decode it.

The problem is that it wont use permission classes for the request object. I would like to know how I can do that.